# Advanced query on more than 6 tables using MySQL is not getting any results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database:

[image]

**Database Explanation**

Where a patient from a table that is not shown called `patient` that contains patient_id and `patient_name_en` can have on each visit to a clinic (table visit) multiple symptoms so he can see multiple doctors/nurses per each visit.

Each doctor can specify multiple diagnosis to the patient and from here you can see that we have a table `diagnosis` connected to `consultation`.

After finishing the consultation doctor should specify what medication the patient should take and how much pills. Here is the part of pharmacy where it contains 3 tables:

1. `medication`: a general medication list;
2. `med_pharmacy`: where if we have a quantity of a specific medication, it will appear in this table;
3. `consultation_med`: where it is connected to `consultation` table and, here we can specify the `med_pharmacy_id` and how much pills the patient is given.

**Expected Result**

I am preparing an html page to generate a report using AJAX-PHP scripts:

[image]

Please take note that **at each visit, a patient can see multiple doctors/nurses, that's why consultation table may contain multiple rows per visit, thus multiple medications may be prescribed**. So at the html page, we will have multiple rows starting from the red colors:

[image]

What I did as a query is the following:

```
select t1.visit_id, 
t1.consultation_type,
t3.patient_name, 
t3.patient_id, 
t3.nationality, 
t1.date_of_visit,
t2.complication_name,
t2.consultation_result,
t5.doctor_name,
t6.nurse_name,
t8.med_name,
t4.given_quantity,
t4.medication_collector
FROM visit t1, consultation t2, patient t3
LEFT JOIN consultation_med t4 USING (consultation_id, med_pharmacy_id, clinic_id)
LEFT JOIN doctor_list t5 USING (doctor_list_id, doctor_name, clinic_id)
LEFT JOIN nurse_list t6 USING (nurse_list_id, nurse_name, clinic_id)
LEFT JOIN med_pharmacy t7 USING (med_pharmacy_id, med_id, clinic_ic)
LEFT JOIN medication t8 USING(med_id, med_name, clinic_id) 
WHERE t1.visit_id = t2.visit_id
AND t2.consultation_id = t4.consultation_id
AND t1.patient_id = t3.patient_id
AND t1.clinic_id = t3.clinic_id
AND t5.doctor_list_id = t2.doctor_list_id
AND t6.nurse_list_id = t2.nurse_list_id
AND t7.med_id = t8.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id='361' AND t1.patient_id='361-0100' AND t1.visit_id='124'
```

And I kept getting this error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'consultation_id' in 'from clause'

Then I tried the following query but still not getting the required result:

```
select t1.visit_id, 
t1.consultation_type,
t3.patient_name_en, 
t3.patient_id, 
t3.nationality, 
t1.date_of_visit,
t2.complication_name,
t2.consultation_result,
t5.doctor_name,
t6.nurse_name,
t8.med_name,
t4.given_quantity,
t4.medication_collector
FROM visit t1 
LEFT JOIN consultation t2 ON t2.consultation_id = t4.consultation_id, patient t3
LEFT JOIN consultation_med t4 
LEFT JOIN doctor_list t5 ON t5.doctor_list_id = t2.doctor_list_id
LEFT JOIN nurse_list t6 ON t6.nurse_list_id = t2.nurse_list_id
LEFT JOIN medication t8 ON t1.clinic_id = t8.clinic_id
LEFT JOIN med_pharmacy t7 ON t7.med_id = t8.med_id

WHERE t1.visit_id = t2.visit_id

AND t1.patient_id = t3.patient_id
AND t1.clinic_id = t3.clinic_id

AND t1.clinic_id='361' AND t1.patient_id='361-0100' AND t1.visit_id='124'
```

These types of big queries with multiple joins is new to me.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN consultation t2 ON t2.consultation_id = t4.consultation_id, patient t3` Why the `,patient t3` on this line If you need another JOIN write another JOIN

Comment: Please post sample data, expected result and actual result, ideally as a SQLFiddle. Also consider better aliases than "t1/t2" - it makes the query harder to understand.

Comment: Okay working on it, but please help me finding a solution. The result expected is exactly at the html page table.

Comment: Do not mix comma and explicit joins in a query, they have different precedence and this may affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I've moved the some cases out of the WHERE clause and replaced these with table joins instead. Some rearranging of joins too as you where joining on tables that hadn't been declared yet.

```
select t1.visit_id, 
t1.consultation_type,
t3.patient_name_en, 
t3.patient_id, 
t3.nationality, 
t1.date_of_visit,
t2.complication_name,
t2.consultation_result,
t5.doctor_name,
t6.nurse_name,
t8.med_name,
t4.given_quantity,
t4.medication_collector
FROM visit t1 
LEFT JOIN consultation t2 ON t1.visit_id = t2.visit_id
LEFT JOIN consultation t3 ON t1.patient_id = t3.patient_id AND t1.clinic_id = t3.clinic_id
LEFT JOIN consultation_med t4 ON t2.consultation_id = t4.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN doctor_list t5 ON t5.doctor_list_id = t2.doctor_list_id
LEFT JOIN nurse_list t6 ON t6.nurse_list_id = t2.nurse_list_id
LEFT JOIN medication t8 ON t1.clinic_id = t8.clinic_id
LEFT JOIN med_pharmacy t7 ON t7.med_id = t8.med_id

WHERE t1.clinic_id='361' 
AND t1.patient_id='361-0100' 
AND t1.visit_id='124'
```

Comment: A very clean and solid solution. I appreciate it.

Comment: You have this duplicate here which it didn't worked properly for me: `LEFT JOIN consultation t2 ON t1.visit_id = t2.visit_id
LEFT JOIN consultation t3 ON t1.patient_id = t3.patient_id AND t1.clinic_id = t3.clinic_id`

Comment: I fixed it to `patient t3` and now I've got endless rows instead of 4 rows

Comment: it seems that it is iterating for each medication I have in `medication t8` table

Comment: Good spots! @droidnation

Comment: So I have 100 medication name in my `medication t8` table and so I got 100 rows as a result. I think the group by should be according to `consultation_med_id` and `consultaion_id` and `visit_id` ?

Comment: Anymore help sir. It is iterating over all medications I have in medication table